# Should these be one, two, three or no questions?

Tags: support, specific-question

I have three similar and short questions about C programming:

1. Is there a shorthand for `argv[*index]` ?
2. Is `my_struct[index].my_member` the same as `my_struct->my_member` or is the later referred to as `my_struct.my_member` and they are different?
3. Is there a shorthand for `(*i)++` ?

Should the above be one question, two questions, three questions, or no question at all for some reason?

Answer (score 4):

All of these are off-topic on this site, as this site focuses on *conceptual* questions about design and architecture issues rather than technical details about language syntax and semantics.

While these would be on-topic at StackOverflow, I have no idea how well received they would be. #2 in particular should be thoroughly covered by any introductory C or C++ tutorial, so I would not be surprised if that got downvoted for lack of research.

Comment: I'm afraid that OP has no option to ask at Stack Overflow - per my reading of [their recent question at MSO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/322194/839601) they are something like rate limited or blocked over there. [Let's help askers who are trying to circumvent question block at Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7020/31260)?

Comment: @gnat How depressingly unsurprising.